Apache POI: How to put an image on a specific location on MS Word document?
This is the code I have:
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();

var img = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/mahdi/Downloads/unnamed.jpg"));
var pic = run.addPicture(img, PictureType.JPEG, "unnamed.jpg", Units.pixelToEMU(400), Units.pixelToEMU(200));

Which is working fine and adding the image to the output .docx file. However, I want to be able to specify position of this image (e.g. 5cm from left and 15cm from top). How can I do that?

The XWPFRun.addPicture adds pictures inline with the text. That is the picture behaves als like a text character. If the need is to add pictures at a special position on the page, then the picture needs to be anchored at the page, for example. That is not supported by Apache POI up to now.
If one knows how the XML in /word/document.xml should look like for this requirement, then one can create the XML into the /word/document.xml.  How to know? Well each *.docx file simply is a ZIP archive containing XML files and other files. So one can create what is needed using Word GUI, save that as  *.docx file, then  unzip that *.docx file and have a look into it.
Doing that, I come to following code which creates a picture at a special position on a page:
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDrawing;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGraphicalObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTAnchor;

public class CreateWordImageAtPosition {

 private static CTAnchor getAnchorWithGraphic(CTDrawing drawing /*inline drawing*/ , 
  String drawingDescr, boolean behind, String relFromH, int posH, String relFromV, int posV) throws Exception {

  CTGraphicalObject graphicalobject = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getGraphic();
  long width = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCx();
  long height = drawing.getInlineArray(0).getExtent().getCy();

  String anchorXML = 
   "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" "
  +"simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"0\" behindDoc=\""+((behind)?1:0)+"\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
  +"<wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
  +"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\""+relFromH+"\"><wp:posOffset>"+posH+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionH>"
  +"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\""+relFromV+"\"><wp:posOffset>"+posV+"</wp:posOffset></wp:positionV>"
  //+"<wp:positionH relativeFrom=\""+relFromH+"\"><wp:align>"+"center"+"</wp:align></wp:positionH>"
  //+"<wp:positionV relativeFrom=\""+relFromV+"\"><wp:align>"+"center"+"</wp:align></wp:positionV>"
  +"<wp:extent cx=\""+width+"\" cy=\""+height+"\"/>"
  +"<wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"0\" b=\"0\"/><wp:wrapNone/>"
  +"<wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"Drawing 0\" descr=\""+drawingDescr+"\"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
  +"</wp:anchor>";

  drawing = CTDrawing.Factory.parse(anchorXML);
  CTAnchor anchor = drawing.getAnchorArray(0);
  anchor.setGraphic(graphicalobject);
  return anchor;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run; 
  InputStream in;
  CTDrawing drawing;
  CTAnchor anchor;

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Picture at position center of page:");

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  int width = Units.toEMU(100);
  int height = Units.toEMU(100);
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", width, height);
  in.close();  
  drawing = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0);

  int posH = Units.toEMU(72*4); // 4 inch
  posH -= width / 2;
  int posV = Units.toEMU(72*5); // 5 inch
  posV -= height / 2;
  anchor = getAnchorWithGraphic(drawing, "samplePict.jpeg", false /*behind text*/, "page", posH, "page", posV);

  drawing.setAnchorArray(new CTAnchor[]{anchor});
  drawing.removeInline(0);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordImageAtPosition.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}


Thanks @Axel. After lots of searches, the solution that I did (which does not need raw XML texts), is to use addPicture as normal but then replace it's inlint element with an anchor, to change it from inline to absolutely positioned on the page. It is not ideas (and definitely not a clean solution), but it works.
